# How can I avoid impossible trait combinations when using multiple imputation?

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I'm working with a fish trait dataset in R, where anatomical constraints dictate that head length (HL) must be less than standard body length (SL), and SL must be less than or equal to total body length (TL). Formally, TL ≥ SL > HL.

However, when using multiple imputation (e.g., the `missForest` or `mice` packages) to handle missing values in my dataset, I encounter imputed values that violate these constraints (e.g., SLs > TLs).

Is there a way to guide the imputation process, or post-process the imputed data, to ensure that anatomical constraints (relationships between traits) are always respected? Below is an example to demonstrate the problem.

```
#Generate Total body lengths (TL)  - tip of snout to tip of caudal fin/tail
set.seed(10)
TLs <- numeric()
for(i in 1:100){
  repeat {
    value <- rpois(1, 4)
        if(value > 0){
      TLs[i] <- value
      break
    }
  }
}

#Generate standard body length (SL) data - tip of snout to end of last vertebra
#TL >= SL. In this case, many species have TL = SL
SLs <- numeric()
for(i in 1:100){
  repeat {
    value <- rpois(1, 4)
    if(value > 0 && value <= TLs[i]){
      SLs[i] <- value
      break
    }
  }
}

#Generate head lengths (HL), must be shorter than TL and SL
perc <- runif(100, 0.05,0.25)
HLs<- SLs*perc

#make a data frame and remove some values, not completely at random random
df <- data.frame(TL = TLs, SL = SLs, HL = HLs)
all_elements <- unlist(df)
total_elements <- length(all_elements)
num_na <- round(total_elements * 0.2)
na_indices <- sample(total_elements, num_na)
all_elements[na_indices] <- NA
new_df <- matrix(all_elements, nrow = nrow(df), ncol = ncol(df))
colnames(new_df) <- colnames(df)
new_df <- as.data.frame(new_df)
lowest_indices <- order(new_df$SL, decreasing = FALSE)[1:10]
new_df$SL[lowest_indices] <- NA

#impute missing data e.g., using missForest
library(missForest)
imp_data <- missForest(new_df)
table(imp_data$ximp$TL>=imp_data$ximp$SL)
#Some SL > TL!
```

I have tried restricting the documented TL and SL data to rows that have both measures (prior to that, mean SL across the dataset was greater than mean TL because the smallest TLs didn't have corresponding SL values i.e., data was not missing at random). However, it still imputed some SL > TL. Any guidance or suggestions on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  [Potentially relevant](https://www.gerkovink.com/miceVignettes/Passive_Post_processing/Passive_imputation_post_processing.html).  See the section _Post processing of the imputations_.

Comment: @Limey, thanks for that link on post processing in the mice package. The data set I'm dealing with has many categorical variables in addition to numeric variables (like in the example above), and mice seems to be having trouble dealing with these categorical variables (I get a "too many weights" error message). I am therefore using missForest instead. This package doesn't appear to have post processing functions, but I can run the post processing manually/outside the package. Thanks again!